# Getting error: expected expression before ‘{’ token in C while trying to verify struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_ID 3
#define LEN_P 30
#define LEN_CIDADE 50
#define AT 40

typedef struct aeroporto
{
    char id[LEN_ID + 1];
    char pais[LEN_P + 1];
    char cidade[LEN_CIDADE + 1];
} Aeroporto;

int findavailablespot(Aeroporto l[AT])
{
    int i = found = 0;
    for (;i<AT;i++) {
        if (l[i] = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"}) //Error in this line
            break;
        if (found)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }    
}
```

So i am creating the structure `aeroporto` then a vector made up of aeroportos and i want to check if {"aaa","bbb","ccc"} shows up inside the vector.
Help?

Sorry for the formatting, new at this

Comment: First, `=` is assignment, comparison is `==`. Second, you can't compare with a structure initializer.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the erroneous line?  That simply isn't valid C syntax.  If that's supposed to be an assignment of a compound literal, you need the type in patentheses before the braces.

Comment: Third, you have to use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If it's an assignment, it doesn't make sense to put it in `if`.

Comment: Several errors in your code. 1. `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison. 2. Where do you ever set `found`? 3. Look up "compound literals."

Comment: @Barmar — agreed, but if it is a comparison instead, it still doesn't make sense; you can't compare structures like that either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It makes "sense", it just doesn't work that way in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `strcmp()` to compare strings. There's no shortcut for doing this with all the members of a structure, you have to test each one individually and combine with `&&`.

You also forgot to set `found` before breaking out of the loop.

```
int i = 0, found = 0;

for (;i<AT;i++) {
    if (strcmp(l[i].id, "aaa") == 0 && strcmp(l[i].pais, "bbb") == 0 && strcmp(l[i].cidade, "ccc")) {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just another thing if i add inside the main: Aeroporto lista_a[AT] = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"}; will this set all lista_a elements as {"aaa","bbb","ccc"} or not?

Comment: No, it will only initialize the first array element. There's no automatic way to repeat the initializer.